# How do I make the logo appear over the background picture?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the logo on top of the background image.

I noticed that setting a float gets it over the image, however it is not in the position that I want it to be in. I set the logo on a separate div with a bootstrap row class (which is probably the reason why it is intervening. What do I do?

```html
<section>
  <div class="row">
    <img src="images/pdlogo.png" alt="logo" height="130px" class="logo">
  </div>
  <div id="formulario" class="col-sm-6 form animated bounceInUp">
    <h1> Ingresa Aqui!</h1>
    <form>
      <div class="formcontainer">
        <label for="nombre">Nombre </label>
        <input type="text" required id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Hugo">
        <label for="apellido">Apellido</label>
        <input type="text" required id="apellido" name="apellido" placeholder="Sanchez">
        <label for="email">Correo Electronico</label>
        <input type="email" required id="email" name="email" placeholder="hugosanchez@gmail.com">
        <label for="telefono">Numero de Telefono</label>
        <input type="tel" required id="telefono" name="telefono" placeholder="78126177">
        <label for="codigo">Codigo de Compra</label>
        <input type="text" required id="codigo" name="codigo" placeholder="PD78907">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Enviar">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 info">
    <h1> 2 Pasajes Gratis</h1>
    <h2>en 2 pasos simples...</h2>
    <h3>(<span>1</span>) Realiza compras en PatioDesign y guarda tus recibos (contienen el codigo especial) </h3>
    <h3>(2) Ingresa a la seccion "Registros" y llena el formulario</h3>
    <h5>La rifa cierra el Marzo 30, 2019 a las 7:00PM</h5>
    <h5>Resultados se enviaran el día siguiente por mail y se anunciaron en esta misma pagina</h5>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you show us the css that places your background-image?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow Sofia!

You can use `position: relative; z-index: 2`. When an object's position is set to relative, it becomes an ordered layer list. By passing z-index: 2, your telling it that within the ordered layers, I want this to be between item 1 and item 3. Make sure your background has a z-index less than your logo for this to work.